# How to use Feature2D (such as SimpleBlobDetector) correctly? (Python + OpenCV)

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to run blob detection using some simple code:

```
img = cv2.imread(args["image"])
height, width, channels = img.shape

params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()

params.filterByColor = True
params.blobColor = 0

blob_detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector(params)
keypoints = blob_detector.detect(img)
```

However I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 37, in <module>
    keypoints = blob_detector.detect(img)
TypeError: Incorrect type of self (must be 'Feature2D' or its derivative)
```

Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Comment: What is the image channel? RGB or gray scale?

Comment: @Saranraj Nambusubramaniyan It is RGB. I've already set `filterByColor = True` though.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If your OpenCV version is `2.x`, then use  `cv2.SimpleBlobDetector()`. Otherwise if your OpenCV version `3.x (or 4.x)`, then use `cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create` to create the detector.

```
## check opencv version and construct the detector
is_v2 = cv2.__version__.startswith("2.")
if is_v2:
    detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector()
else:
    detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create()

## detect 
kpts = detector.detect(img)
```

Comment: Oh! That wasn't obvious at all. Do you know where that's documented? All of the other SO questions I saw use `SimpleBlobDetector(params)` to create the detector.