# detecting circular black blobs in python using opencv

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I want to detect circular round black blobs in opencv2

```
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector(params)

keypoints = detector.detect(im)
```

I am getting error:

```
keypoints = detector.detect(im)
```

> TypeError: Incorrect type of self (must be 'Feature2D' or its
>   derivative)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Feature2D(such as SimpleBlobDetector) correctly? (Python + OpenCV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48136978/how-to-use-feature2dsuch-as-simpleblobdetector-correctly-python-opencv)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this instead:

```
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)
```

This changed with OpenCV version 2 onwards.